# javaregex - replace multiple occurrances of same pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have this simple program where I am trying to replace multiple occurrences of $P_NAME$ with a string.

```
public static void replaceAllTest() {
    String textBanner = "This advertisement on $P_NAME$ will make the $P_NAME$ very popular";               
    Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("\\$(.*)\\$");
    Matcher matcherValue = replace.matcher(textBanner);
    String updatedValue = matcherValue.replaceFirst("DotCom");
    System.out.println(updatedValue);
}
```

I expect the output to be `This advertisement on DotCom will make the DotCom very popular` but the output I get `This advertisement on DotCom very popular`. Basically the `replaceAll` is removing all text till the next occurrence of the pattern.

Please help.

Comment: Why not just use `"\\$P_NAME\\$"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [non-greedy regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) with `\\$(.*?)\\$`:

```
public static void replaceAllTest() {
    String textBanner = "This advertisement on $P_NAME$ will make the $P_NAME$ very popular";               
    Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("\\$(.*?)\\$"); // <-- non-greedy here with "?"
    Matcher matcherValue = replace.matcher(textBanner);
    String updatedValue = matcherValue.replaceAll("DotCom"); // <-- replaceAll to replace all matches
    System.out.println(updatedValue);
}
```